# Wordpress - redirect url to another template single- {post_type} - {other} .php?

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a `custom_post_type = "post_type"` There is a post output `template = "single-post_type.php"`

It is necessary that when clicking on the link **mywebsite.com/post_type/post_name/second**, not `single-post_type.php` would be loaded, but for example `single-post_type-second.php`.

In this case, you must save `single-post_type.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decision - [template_include](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/)

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_post_type_second' );
function include_post_type_second( $template ) {
    if ( (in_array('second', explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))) ) {
        if ( $new_template = locate_template( array( 'single-post_type-second.php' ) ) )
            $template = $new_template ;
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to make another custom page type:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'another_post_type' );
function another_post_type( $template ) {
    if ( (in_array('second', explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))) ) {
        if ( $template2 = locate_template( array( 'single-post_type-second.php' ) ) )
            $template1 = $template2 ;
    }
    return $template1;
}
```